# Python program in which there is an option for one or two players

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3 question...

The assignment has to do with adding a second player option to a one-player dice roll game.  If there are two players, both players take turns rolling until termination, and then roll totals for each player are calculated.  Same idea for one player.

Here is the code for a one-player game without the option for a second player--

```
    import random
    INTMIN=1
    INTMAX=6

    def welcome():
        print("Welcome to the Roll the Dice game!")
        player=input("What is your name? ")
        return player

    def roll():
        con='yes'
        while con=='yes':
            die_one=random.randint(1,6)
            die_two=random.randint(1,6)
            v=is_doubles(die_one,die_two)
            if not v:
                print("You rolled  " + str(die_one) + " and " + str(die_two))
            con=input("Do you want to continue yes/no: ")

    def is_doubles(die_one,die_two):
        if die_one==die_two:
            print("You have doubles: " + str(die_one) + " and " + str(die_two))
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def main():
        n=welcome()
        roll()
        print("Thank you for playing, " + n)
        input("End of program.")

    main()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't ask us to do your homework for you. We will gladly help you with your code, but we ain't gonna do all your work.

Comment: +1 for using the correct singular "die".

Answer (score 3):

Here a quick and dirty solution (python3):

```
(lambda f,r,p1,p2:print('\n\n{} has a score of {}.\n{} has a score of {}.\n\nTh'
'ank you for playing.'.format(*(lambda a,b,c,d:(a,c,b,d))(p1,p2,*(lambda f,r,p1,
p2:f(f,r,p1,p2,0,0,*[r.randint(1,6) for _ in 'babe']))(f,r,p1,p2)))))(lambda f,r
,p1,p2,a1,a2,r1,r2,r3,r4:f(f,r,p1,p2,a1+r1+r2,a2+r3+r4,*[r.randint (1,6)for _ in
'babe'])if input(('\n{} has rolled{}: {} and {}.\n'*2+'\nDo you want to continu'
'e? [yes/*] ').format(p1,' a double' if r1==r2 else'',r1,r2,p2,' a double' if r3
==r4 else'',r3,r4))=='yes'else(a1+r1+r2,a2+r3+r4),__import__('random'),input('W'
'elcome\nWhat is your name? '),input('What is your name? '))
```

If I were your teacher I would be quite astonished at this answer.

Remember a few things:

- Readability counts.
- Variable names are for sissies.
- The code was hard to write, it should be hard to read.

**Seriously:**

Without showing any effort, few people will do your homework.

Comment: @kdazzle Well, it is legit python and I hope it complies with OP's requirements.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to consider my code.  Could you explain to me how this fits into the code I posted?  Also, the computer is supposed to prompt the user for input as to whether there will be one player or two players.

Comment: @user3063941 It doesn't need to "fit" into your code. It is running "as is". Just try it. Prompting the user for 1- or 2-player mode should be an easy expansion of my snippet.

Comment: I did.  It works fine.  How would it translate, though, into the code I posted (in other words, into distinct functions in standard Python style)?

Comment: I am a beginner programmer, by the way.

Comment: @user3063941 A `lambda` is nothing more and nothing else than a function. Take the lambdas, give them a name and you are set.

Comment: Since I am a beginner programmer, could you explain the lambda in simpler terms?

Comment: That's one of the reasons I'm dividing up my program into simple functions.

Comment: If you have the time, could you comment on the code I posted?